# How do I get the values of all selected checkboxes in a Django request.POST?

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi I have an array of checkboxes e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="4" />
```

How do I access these in the view.py if more than one is selected?

I have tried

```
request.POST['checks']
```

but that only gives me the last value.  What I want is all the ones that have been selected in a list e.g. 1,3,4

Thanks

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Try this:

```
some_var = request.POST.getlist('checks')
```

`some_var` will contain `[1,3,4]` (those values that were checked)

Answer (score 40):

This will fix your problem,

```
some_var = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')
```

If you write `some_var = request.POST.getlist('checks')` may not work properly.

Comment: This is the way you need to do it for Django 1.8+ (I am not sure on the earlier versions or what version the OP was using at the time).

Comment: Did you mean `getlist('checks', [])`? If so, at least in [version 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist), the brackets are not required. `getlist` will return an empty list by default, for missing keys.

Answer (score 1):

this is will work:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="4" />
```

views.py

```
some_var = request.POST.getlist('checks[]')
```

Comment: Is there any need to provide an answer that is already available?.