# For a checkbox with multiple values in my html template how to access it through python code?

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I'm a `python` and `django` newbie.

This is in my `html` template

```
<input type ="checkbox" value={{ item.id }} name="ck1[]">
```

In views.py when i do a `checked = request.POST.get(['ck1'])` i get unhasable list error. Kindly guide me.

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417127/how-do-i-get-the-values-of-all-selected-checkboxes-in-a-django-request-post/12951803#12951803) may helps u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u want to get array from html in Django view u need to use

`checked = request.POST.getlist('ck1[]')`

or

`checked = request.POST.getlist('ck1')`

getlist method will convert all selected values into python list

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use PHP syntax when you're writing Django. `name="ck1[]"` is a PHP-ism that's completely unnecessary.

If you want the field to be called `ck1`, just call use `name="ck1"`, and use `request.POST.getlist('ck1') in your view.

If you really have to use that horrible bracket syntax, you'll need to use `request.POST.getlist('ck1[]')`, because Django quite sensibly believes that the name you use in the HTML is the name you should get in the POST data.